# Bash - How do I write a script that will ssh into a given ip?

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, terminal

How would I write a Bash script that takes a single param (the ip of my remote server) and sshs into it? I tried searching for a ready-made solution, but found nothing so I apologize if this is a dupe of another question.

Comment: How are you going to authenticate session with the server?
key-based or prompt password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you have to do is `ssh` it's very short:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh user@$1
```

I suppose it would prompt for a password?

Then `expect` is what you'd want:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set ip [lindex $argv 0]
spawn user@$ip
expect "assword:"
send "<password>\r"
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually was able to figure out with a little trial and error. I just put this guy in my .bashrc file and it works like a charm.

```
ipssh () {
    ssh root@$1 -i ~/.ssh/$2;
}
```

Comment: I would suggest looking into using ssh config 
Below is nice tutorial give it a read. 
http://nerderati.com/2011/03/17/simplify-your-life-with-an-ssh-config-file/

Comment: That's great stuff. Thank you!